# For which polynomials $p(x)$ is $p(p(x))+p(x)$=$x^4+3x^2+3$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For which polynomials $p(x)$ is $p(p(x))+p(x)$=$x^4+3x^2+3$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Since the power of the right hand side is 4, $p(x)$ has to be 2.
So I assumed a solution of: $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and then i put it in $p(p(x))+p(x)$ and got:
$a(ax^2+bc+c)^2+b(ax^2+bx+c)+c+ax^2+bx+c=x^4+3x^2+3$

To find the coefficients I tried $x=0$ and got 
$ac^2+bc+2c=3$. But here I'm stuck, how do I go from here?

Comment: Coefficients of all powers of $x$ on the two sides have to be the same. Write down $5$ equations and solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying the coefficient of $x^4$ one gets $a=1$ and then the coefficient of $x^3$ you get $b=0$ hence $c=1$ or $c=-3$. Then check that $x^2+1$ is indeed a solution while $x^2-3$ is not.

Comment: You have $a^2=1$, so why do you rule out the case $a=-1$?  (It is indeed the case that $a=-1$ does not contribute to a solution, but this hasn't been proven.)

Comment: @Batominovski The coefficient at $x^4$ is $a^3$, equating that to $1$ gives you $a=1$...

Comment: @5xum  My bad!  Sorry, Anna!

Comment: Interestingly, even if we allow $a$, $b$, and $c$ to be complex numbers, $(a,b,c)=(1,0,1)$ is still the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomials

$$Ax^5+Bx^4+Cx^3+Dx^2+Ex+F$$
and 
$$ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$$

are equal for all $x$ **if and only if**

$$A=a\\B=b\\C=c\\D=d\\E=e\\F=f$$